# AddComponent("Rigidbody") or another component doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, components, unityscript

I am trying to program a very simple FPS game and I reached a point where I need to create a pickup weapon system. In order to finish that system, I am stuck on a point where I need to `AddComponent("Rigidbody")` and `AddComponent("BoxCollider")` and Unity3D throws that error:

> 'AddComponent is not a member of 'WeaponPickUp'

Where `WeaponPickUp` is my Javascript script file.

Below is my code:

```
 #pragma strict

 var pickup = false;
 var check = 2;

 function Update () {
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("pickup") && check % 2 == 0){
         GetObject();
         pickup = true;
         check = check + 1;
     }
     else if (Input.GetButtonDown("pickup") && (check % 2 == 1)){
         pickup = false;
         check = check - 1;
         this.AddComponent("Rigidbody") as Rigidbody;
         this.AddComponent("BoxCollider") as BoxCollider;
         this.GetComponent(BoxCollider).enabled = true;
     }
 }

 function GetObject(){
     var position : GameObject = GameObject.Find("weaponPosition");
     this.transform.position = position.transform.position;
     Destroy(GetComponent(Rigidbody));
     Destroy(GetComponent(BoxCollider));
     this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
     this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FirstPersonCharacter").transform;
     //    this.transform.parentposition
 }
```

I've no idea why this happens. Anybody willing to help me out, I will appreciate it as always!

Comment: When Unity throws an error, it comes with the line number, which line is giving you the error?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
this.AddComponent("Rigidbody") as Rigidbody;
this.AddComponent("BoxCollider") as BoxCollider;
this.GetComponent(BoxCollider).enabled = true;
```

needs to be

```
gameObject.AddComponent("Rigidbody") as Rigidbody;
gameObject.AddComponent("BoxCollider") as BoxCollider;
gameObject.GetComponent(BoxCollider).enabled = true;
```

Same for the `Destroy` lines

`AddComponent` is part of `GameObject`, not your `WeaponPickUp`

Comment: AddComponent and GetComponent use generic types. Shouldn't it be `gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>()`

Comment: @Okomikeruko `GetComponent()`/`AddComponent()` have both a generic type version and one which takes a string name as a parameter. Either version is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm rather partial to generic types myself. Saves the trouble of having to cast the result.

Comment: Then if he's using the string method, then he has to use `" "` around his strings, right?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `this` keyword with `gameObject` then remove `as Rigidbody` and `as BoxCollider`

This is what it should look like:

```
gameObject.AddComponent("Rigidbody");
gameObject.AddComponent("BoxCollider");
gameObject.GetComponent("BoxCollider").enabled = true;
```

The syntax above should have worked but it is obsolete. It changed in Unity 5.
You will get error if you do it like that. Below is the new syntax and right way to do it now.

```
GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
GetComponent.<BoxCollider>();
GetComponent.<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
```

Your whole code:

```
#pragma strict

var pickup = false;
var check = 2;

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("pickup") && check % 2 == 0){
        GetObject();
        pickup = true;
        check = check + 1;
    }
    else if (Input.GetButtonDown("pickup") && (check % 2 == 1)){
        pickup = false;
        check = check - 1;
        GetComponent.<Rigidbody>();
        GetComponent.<BoxCollider>();
        GetComponent.<BoxCollider>().enabled = true;
    }
}

function GetObject(){
    var position : GameObject = GameObject.Find("weaponPosition");
    this.transform.position = position.transform.position;
    Destroy(GetComponent(Rigidbody));
    Destroy(GetComponent(BoxCollider));
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform;
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FirstPersonCharacter").transform;
    //    this.transform.parentposition
}
```